# how to pass the selected option as value in moodle select

Tags: php, moodle

i want to pass the options as values : here is my code.

```
  $master_id=array();
        $ret1="select Id from m_tl_mastercourse";
        $result1=get_records_sql($ret1,$limitfrom='', $limitnum='');
        foreach($result1 as $resu){
            $master_id[ ]=$resu->Id;
           
         }
       
    $mform->addElement('select', 'master_id', get_string('selectcourse'), $master_id);
```

If i  use this means it is looking like below :

```
<select id="id_master_id" name="master_id">
<option value="0">php01</option>
<option value="1">ios01</option>
<option value="2">and01</option>
<option value="3">java01</option>
<option value="4">python01</option>
<option value="5">yii2</option>
```

what i want is the exact value will be pass in to the option values. how to get that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this with the get records menu functions.

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#get_records_menu

```
$options = $DB->get_records_menu('m_tl_mastercourse', [], 'id', 'id, name');

$mform->addElement('select', 'master_id', get_string('selectcourse'), $options);
```

To pass the selected value, you need to pass the value to the form.

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Form_API#Usage

```
$formdata = new \stdClass();
$formdata->master_id = 99

$mform = new edit_form();
$mform->set_data($formdata);
$mform->display();
```

Comment: I misread your question, so updated the answer,

Answer (score 1):

You're adding to the array as `$master_id[ ]=$resu->Id;` which by default assigns a numeric index to the array and gives you the next available index number. Assign the key yourself as follows:

- `$master_id[$resu->Id]=$resu->Id;`

Note, this assumes that all of your possible options are unique.